# java StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, discord

I am trying to write a discord bot.
Now i have the following problem:
First i load the prefix with String prefix = Setttings.readSetting("Prefix");
Then i test if the message received from the discord starts with the prefix.
If this test passes, i crop the Message and extract the command itself and execute
the method in the class of the method. But here's my problem:
When my prefix is longer than 1 character i get a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at listener.CommandManager.onGuildMessageReceived(CommandManager.java:38)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter.onEvent(ListenerAdapter.java:395)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:96)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handle(EventManagerProxy.java:64)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.JDAImpl.handleEvent(JDAImpl.java:165)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.MessageCreateHandler.handleInternally(MessageCreateHandler.java:97)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:36)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onDispatch(WebSocketClient.java:881)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onEvent(WebSocketClient.java:769)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:748)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:919)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:385)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:276)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:996)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:755)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
```

Here's the code of the class:

```
package listener;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;
import tools.Settings;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import commands.*;

import assets.Command;

public class CommandManager extends ListenerAdapter {

    private static Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<String, Command>(); //here's where i store all the commands

    public static void init() { //In this method i put all the commands in the ArrayList. I call it on Program Start.

        commands.put("test", new TestCommand());

    }

    @Override
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {

        String prefix = Settings.readSetting("Prefix"); //Here i load the prefix.

        if(event.getMessage().getContentDisplay().startsWith(prefix)) {

            try {

                Command c = commands.get(event.getMessage().getContentDisplay().split(" ")[0].substring(prefix.length())); //Here occurs the error.

                if(c != null) {

                    c.execute(event);

                } else {

                    event.getChannel().sendMessage("Sorry, that command doesn't exist").queue();

                }

            } catch(Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Does anyone know the error and/or how to fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: This is where your problem is. What do you expect this to do? `.split(" ")[0].substring(prefix.length())`  Why are you using `substring` when you've already split the string on space? Index 0 will have `prefix` and index 1 will have the first argument.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider what? index 0 will have the prefix and anything connected without a space. "!hello world".split(" ") would be ["!hello", "world"] where "!" would be the prefix.

Comment: How was anyone supposed to know that? It's not clarified in the question. A command with a `prefix` could just as easily be `prefix arg0 arg1 ... argN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, about the specific exception: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-array-indexoutofbounds-exception-in-java/

An `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is usually thrown, if an array (or `String`) is accessed in such a way, that the argument index is outside the array's index range.

In your case, the exception is thrown, because the string split you perform probably does not return a value in the array at index 0 that is as long as `prefix.length()`. Or to put it another way: What happens if the message returned by `getMessage` is smaller than the length of your prefix?

Practical example:

```java
// assume this input:
String prefix = "Hello";
String messageContentDisplay = "Hello Jack";

// your code does:
String[] segments = messageContentDisplay.split(" ");
String prefixInMessage = segments[0];
String subMessage = prefixInMessage.substring(prefix.length()); // This makes no sense.
```

I believe what you actually want is to cut the prefix, which would work like this:

```java
String displayContent = event.getMessage().getContentDisplay();
String[] segments = displayContent.split(" ");
if (segments.length > 1) {
    Command c = commands.get(displayContent.substring(segments[0].length));
}
```